# How to use Expansion Tile with ListView inside Column in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a custom drawer.

I want to make `DrawerHeader` fixed. However, I want `ExpansionTile` and `ListView` scrollable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdqFI.jpg ,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN0YN.jpg

```
 class _NavigationDrawerState extends State<NavigationDrawer> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          DrawerHeader(
            child: Column(....),
          ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('Roles'),
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                itemBuilder: _buildRolesList,
                itemCount: roles.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
              )
            ],
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: _buildList,
            itemCount: myList.length,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(icons[myList[index].toLowerCase()]),
      title: Text(myList[index]),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRolesList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      dense: true,
      title: Text(roles[index]),
      onTap: () {},
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
class _NavigationDrawerState extends State<NavigationDrawer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ExpansionTile(
            title: Text('Roles'),
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: _buildRolesList,
                  itemCount: roles.length,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: _buildList,
              itemCount: myList.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(icons[myList[index].toLowerCase()]),
      title: Text(myList[index]),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRolesList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      dense: true,
      title: Text(roles[index]),
      onTap: () {},
    );
}
```

Comment: Adding a sized box for the listview builder helped define the expansion box size.  However, it did not prevent overflow caused from the ExpansionPanel size being to small.

Comment: I used the ConfigurableExpansionTitle https://github.com/matthewstyler/configurable_expansion_tile/tree/master/lib to create a resizable ExpansionTile